# What to do about highly-upvoted posts that have become broken due to removal of an external resource?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, broken-link

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3821731/1709587) (now deleted) relied entirely upon an image hosted off-site. That image is now broken, and pretty much the only content that remains in the post is some links to tangentially-related off-site resources.

The poster has been informed twice in the last year of this but has not fixed his post. I've tried going to [the Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20130710005333/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821703/testing-jquery-statements-in-chrome-javascript-console) in order to fix it myself, but the Wayback Machine doesn't have the image. Unless the answerer himself fixes it, it would be beneficial for it be deleted; it is currently nothing but noise.

However, I can't flag it as low-quality, presumably because it is too highly upvoted.

So what should I do? Is a mod flag appropriate in these circumstances, and would a moderator take it upon themselves to delete such a post?

Comment: I don't see the problem. It clearly says "alt text" there, so the image must have depicted some sort of alternate text, right? Right?